# Change innerHTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Well I have that code:

```
<script>

function changeInner(id, inner) {
 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<textarea>" + inner + "</textarea>"
}

</script>

<span id="edit" onlick="javascript:changeInner('edit', 'More text in a Textarea!');">Some text!</span>
```

Why it doesn't work? It's too simple, and it doesn't work, I don't know why...

Comment: Try `onclick` instead of `onlick` :p

Comment: Woah! I'm so silly... xD Thanks! :P

Comment: It always happens to me... Idk why...

Comment: Maybe add `;` at the end of `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<textarea>" + inner + "</textarea>"`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your html markup. Changing `onlick` to `onclick` makes everything work.

```
<span id="edit" onclick="...
```